# How to get elements inside tags using queryselector?

Tags: javascript, list, typescript, htmlelements

```
var divElement = document.createElement("div");
divElement.setAttribute('id', 'Items');

var ulElement = document.createElement("ul");
var liElement = document.createElement("li");
var spanElement1 = document.createElement("span");
var spanElement2 = document.createElement("span");
liElement.appendChild(spanElement1);
liElement.appendChild(spanElement2);
ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
```

when I enter selector query, I cant get elements.

> **document.querySelectorAll("divElement ul li");** should give
>   **document.querySelectorAll("#Items ul li");**

but its not working, how to get the id at runtime????

Comment: Use whitespace instead of dot.

Comment: Its not working @kindUser

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('divElement ul li')`. I've checked it. It works.

Answer (score 5):

finally came up with solution. we can get **"id"** from the user using ***getElementById*** and then its simple to apply ***query selector***.

> document.getElementById(id).querySelectorAll('ul li');

Answer (score 2):

Use `divElement.querySelectorAll('ul li')` if you still have access to `divElement` or `document.querySelectorAll('div ul li')` without access.

Note how there is no dot. `.` are use for classes in CSS. For element you simply use the tag name.

`divElement` is the reference of the element you created in JS but its CSS selector is `div` not `divElement`. JS name variable cannot be used within the selector string.

Good read on the subject [querySelectorAll doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [how css selectors work](https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/)

Answer (score 2):

you can get element by id then use query selector like so:
  `console.log(document.getElementById('details').querySelectorAll('ul li'))`

```
<ul id="details"> == $0
    <li>
      <span>
         <label>TEST</label>
         <p>GEORGE</p>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>
        <label>TEST_TWO</label>
        <p>2131</p>
          </span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to study `querySelectorAll` first

Basic Syntax

```
elementList = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
```

In your case

```
elementList = document.querySelectorAll(div ul li);
```

here are helpful [links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

Comment: How can I access it "document.querySelectorAll(div#id ul li)" generically? @mirzaObaid

Comment: if you are using html elements then you will use spaces like "document.querySelectorAll(div ul li)" but if you are using any class or id then "document.querySelectorAll(div#id ul li)" or "document.querySelectorAll(div .classname ul li)"

Comment: How can I get the id for div element generically?? @MirzaObaid

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll here are lots of examples